# Laravel Blade is not properly updating from Database. Is there any problem in my controller? In admin panel all are properly showing complete data

Tags: php, laravel

In making output in my blade view in laravel it does not output all data gathered from database. Is there any wrong in my code? I it shows only some of my data from laravel but not all shows.

[Admin View as you can see here its upto page 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsG0J.png)

[User View as you can see here there is only 4 pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRibw.png)

User Controller (Problem in showing data from database):

Here is my problem in this controller

```
    $this->middleware('auth');

}
public function shareLinks()
{

    $user = Auth::user();
    $settings = Settings::first();

    $ad_limit = $user->membership->ad_limit;

    $membership = $user->membership->id;

    $ad = Share::whereUser_id($user->id)->where('date','=',date('Y-m-d'))->count();

    if ($ad == 0)
    {
        $ptcse = Link::whereMembership_id($membership)->take($ad_limit)->whereStatus(1)->count();

        if ($ptcse == 0){

            session()->flash('message', 'Sorry To Say You That Currently there is no Cash Links for you. Please wait or upgrade your membership, ');
            Session::flash('type', 'error');
            Session::flash('title', 'Error');

            return redirect()->route('userMemberships');

        }
        else {

            $ptcs = Link::whereMembership_id($membership)->take($ad_limit)->whereStatus(1)->get();

            foreach ($ptcs as $ptc)
            {
                $info =([

                    'user_id'=> $user->id,
                    'date'=> date('Y-m-d'),
                    'link_id'=> $ptc->id,

                ]);

                Share::create($info);
            }

            $adverts = Share::whereUser_id($user->id)->where('date','=',date('Y-m-d'))->paginate(10);

            return view('user.viewads.share',compact('adverts','settings'));

        }

    }else{

        $adverts = Share::whereUser_id($user->id)->where('date','=',date('Y-m-d'))->paginate(10);
        return view('user.viewads.share',compact('adverts','settings'));
    }

}
public function save_share($id) {

    $user = Auth::user();
    $advert= Share::findOrFail($id);
    if ($advert-> status == 1){

        session()->flash('message', 'This task has been already completed.');
        Session::flash('type', 'warning');
        Session::flash('title', 'Un-Successful');

        return redirect()->route('userLink.share');
    }
    $advert->status = 1;
    $advert->save();
    $rewards = $advert->link->rewards;
    $profile = $user->profile;
    $profile->main_balance = $profile->main_balance + $rewards;
    $profile->save();
    $log = UserLog::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'reference' => str_random(12),
        'type' => 1,
        'for' => 'Cash Links',
        'from' => 'Self',
        'details'=>'You receive a reward for completing a task.',
        'amount'=>$rewards,
    ]);
    $upliner = Referral::whereUser_id($user->id)->count();
    if ($upliner == 1){
        $settings = Settings::first();
        $referral = Referral::whereUser_id($user->id)->first();
        $upliner = $referral->reflink->user->profile;
        $percentage = $settings->referral_advert;
        $commission = (($percentage / 100) * $rewards);
        $upliner->referral_balance = $upliner->referral_balance + $commission;
        $upliner->save();
        $referral->total = $referral->total + $commission;
        $referral->today = $referral->today + $commission;
        $referral->save();
        $log = UserLog::create([
            'user_id' => $referral->reflink->user->id,
            'reference' => str_random(12),
            'for' => 'Referral',
            'type' => 2,
            'from' => $user->name,
            'details'=>'You receive a referral bonus.',
            'amount'=>$commission,
        ]);
    }

    session()->flash('message', 'This task has been successfully completed.');
    Session::flash('type', 'success');
    Session::flash('title', 'Success');

    $robi = "success";

    return response()->json(array('robi'=>$robi), 200);

}



public function cashLinks()
{

    $user = Auth::user();
    $settings = Settings::first();

    $ad_limit = $user->membership->ad_limit;

    $membership = $user->membership->id;

    $ad = Advert::whereUser_id($user->id)->where('date','=',date('Y-m-d'))->count();

    if ($ad == 0)
    {
        $ptcse = Ptc::whereMembership_id($membership)->take($ad_limit)->whereStatus(1)->count();

        if ($ptcse == 0){

            session()->flash('message', 'Sorry To Say You That Currently there is no Cash Links for you. Please wait or upgrade your membership, ');
            Session::flash('type', 'error');
            Session::flash('title', 'Error');

            return redirect()->route('userMemberships');

        }
        else {

            $ptcs = Ptc::whereMembership_id($membership)->take($ad_limit)->whereStatus(1)->get();

            foreach ($ptcs as $ptc)
            {
                $info =([

                    'user_id'=> $user->id,
                    'date'=> date('Y-m-d'),
                    'ptc_id'=> $ptc->id,

                ]);

                Advert::create($info);
            }

            $adverts = Advert::whereUser_id($user->id)->where('date','=',date('Y-m-d'))->paginate(10);

            return view('user.viewads.index',compact('adverts','settings'));

        }

    }else{

        $adverts = Advert::whereUser_id($user->id)->where('date','=',date('Y-m-d'))->paginate(10);
        return view('user.viewads.index',compact('adverts','settings'));
    }

}

public function cashLinkConfirm($id)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $advert= Advert::findOrFail($id);

    if ($advert-> status == 1){

        session()->flash('message', 'This task has been already completed.');
        Session::flash('type', 'warning');
        Session::flash('title', 'Un-Successful');
        return redirect()->route('userCash.links');
    }

    if ($advert->ptc->type == 2){

        $advert->ptc->order->totalhit =  $advert->ptc->order->totalhit +1;
        $advert->ptc->order->save();
    }
    $advert->status = 1;
    $advert->save();

    $advert->ptc->count = $advert->ptc->count + 1;
    $advert->ptc->save();

    $rewards = $advert->ptc->rewards;
    $profile = $user->profile;
    $profile->main_balance = $profile->main_balance + $rewards;
    $profile->save();

    $log = UserLog::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'reference' => str_random(12),
        'type' => 1,
        'for' => 'Cash Links',
        'from' => 'Self',
        'details'=>'You receive a reward for completing a task.',
        'amount'=>$rewards,
    ]);
    $upliner = Referral::whereUser_id($user->id)->count();
    if ($upliner == 1){
        $settings = Settings::first();
        $referral = Referral::whereUser_id($user->id)->first();
        $upliner = $referral->reflink->user->profile;
        $percentage = $settings->referral_advert;
        $commission = (($percentage / 100) * $rewards);
        $upliner->referral_balance = $upliner->referral_balance + $commission;
        $upliner->save();
        $referral->total = $referral->total + $commission;
        $referral->today = $referral->today + $commission;
        $referral->save();
        $log = UserLog::create([
            'user_id' => $referral->reflink->user->id,
            'reference' => str_random(12),
            'for' => 'Referral',
            'type' => 2,
            'from' => $user->name,
            'details'=>'You receive a referrral bonus.',
            'amount'=>$commission,
        ]);
    }

    session()->flash('message', 'This task has been successfully completed.');
    Session::flash('type', 'success');
    Session::flash('title', 'Success');
    return redirect()->route('userCash.links');
}
public function cashLinkShow($id)
{

    $advert= Advert::findOrFail($id);

    if ($advert->ptc->status == 0){

        $advert->status = 1;
        $advert->save();

        session()->flash('message', 'This task has expired.');
        Session::flash('type', 'warning');
        Session::flash('title', 'Un-Successful');

        return redirect()->route('userCash.links');
    }

    if ($advert->ptc->hit == $advert->ptc->count){

        $advert->ptc->status = 2;
        $advert->ptc->save();

        if ($advert->ptc->type == 2){

            $advert->ptc->order->status = 2;
            $advert->ptc->order->save();
        }

        $advert->status = 1;
        $advert->save();

        session()->flash('message', 'This task has expired or traffic limit reached. You will not get any reward.');
        Session::flash('type', 'warning');
        Session::flash('title', 'Un-Successful');

        return redirect()->route('userCash.links');
    }


    return view('user.viewads.showads', compact('advert'));

}

public function cashVideoConfirm($id)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $video= Video::findOrFail($id);

    if ($video-> status == 1){

        session()->flash('message', 'This task has been already completed.');
        Session::flash('type', 'warning');
        Session::flash('title', 'Un-Successful');

        return redirect()->route('userCash.videos');




    }

    $video->status = 1;
    $video->save();

    $rewards = $video->ppv->rewards;

    $profile = $user->profile;

    $profile->main_balance = $profile->main_balance + $rewards;

    $profile->save();

    $log = UserLog::create([

        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'reference' => str_random(12),
        'for' => 'Cash Video',
        'type' => 1,
        'from' => 'Self',
        'details'=>'You receive a reward for completing a task.',
        'amount'=>$rewards,

    ]);

    $upliner = Referral::whereUser_id($user->id)->count();

    if ($upliner == 1){

        $settings = Settings::first();

        $referral = Referral::whereUser_id($user->id)->first();

        $upliner = $referral->reflink->user->profile;

        $percentage = $settings->referral_advert;

        $commission = (($percentage / 100) * $rewards);

        $upliner->referral_balance = $upliner->referral_balance + $commission;

        $upliner->save();
        $referral->total = $referral->total + $commission;
        $referral->today = $referral->today + $commission;
        $referral->save();

        $log = UserLog::create([

            'user_id' => $referral->reflink->user->id,
            'reference' => str_random(12),
            'for' => 'Referral',
            'type' => 2,
            'from' => $user->name,
            'details'=>'You receive a referral bonus.',
            'amount'=>$commission,

        ]);

    }


    session()->flash('message', 'This task has been successfully completed.');
    Session::flash('type', 'success');
    Session::flash('title', 'Success');

    return redirect()->route('userCash.videos');


}





public function cashVideoShow($id)
{

    $video= Video::findOrFail($id);
    return view('user.viewads.vshow', compact('video'));

}


public function cashVideos()
{

    $user = Auth::user();
    $settings = Settings::first();

    $ad_limit = $user->membership->ad_limit;

    $membership = $user->membership->id;

    $ad = Video::whereUser_id($user->id)->where('date','=',date('Y-m-d'))->count();

    if ($ad == 0)
    {
        $ppvse = Ppv::whereMembership_id($membership)->take($ad_limit)->whereStatus(1)->count();

        if ($ppvse == 0){

            session()->flash('message', 'Sorry To Say You That Currently there is no Cash Videos for you. Please wait or upgrade your membership, ');
            Session::flash('type', 'error');
            Session::flash('title', 'Error');

            return redirect()->route('userMemberships');

        }
        else {

            $ppvs = Ppv::whereMembership_id($membership)->take($ad_limit)->whereStatus(1)->get();

            foreach ($ppvs as $ppv)
            {
                $info =([

                    'user_id'=> $user->id,
                    'date'=> date('Y-m-d'),
                    'ppv_id'=> $ppv->id,

                ]);

                Video::create($info);
            }

            $videos = Video::whereUser_id($user->id)->where('date','=',date('Y-m-d'))->paginate(10);

            return view('user.viewads.vindex',compact('videos','settings'));

        }

    }else{

        $videos = Video::whereUser_id($user->id)->where('date','=',date('Y-m-d'))->paginate(10);
        return view('user.viewads.vindex',compact('videos','settings'));
    }



}
```

Admin Preview Controller:

```
    return view('admin.paidtoclick.index', compact('advertisements'));


}
public function preview($id)
{

    $log = Ptc::findOrFail($id);

    return view('admin.paidtoclick.preview', compact('log'));


}
```

Comment: There is a lot of code in your question and not much detail other than it doesn't work. Can you narrow down your code to only the function/statements that you're having issues with, include your blade output and a bit more detail as that might help.

Comment: Check it out I added a picture which you can see what I'm pointing out :<

Comment: Check my picture I edited it